# Where to get ubuntu linux kernel source package?

Tags: kernel, source-code

Where to get Ubuntu Linux kernel source package from? Not a Debian package.
Is there any repository which has tar/bz2 package of complete kernel sources of every version release.

Comment: Just simple run `apt-get source linux`, you will get original tarball + *debianization*.

Comment: @0andriy You could post your comment as additional answer.

Comment: @ByteCommander, it's already been marked as duplicate to the same answer.  Moreover, reading again the question I think it's actually **not** a duplicate of that since OP asks about Git or alike repos, which first answer here suits.

Answer (score 3):

There is a git repository for Ubuntu kernels.

It is http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/

To get sources using git run

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git
```

For instance you can get Ubuntu 16.04 kernel sources from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git

17.04 sources are at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-zesty.git

Answer (score -2):

The answer to your question, you can find the Linux Kernel Archives at the following site.

https://www.kernel.org/

You can download the tarball.

Comment: For Ubuntu? Are you sure?

Comment: @0andriy, would you please enlight me is there any Ubuntu Linux kernel source package available? Would you elaborate your question? You mean to say Ubuntu Linux kernel is different than main stream Linux kernel?

Comment: Yes, it's different. It has tons of patches on top of vanilla version.