# How to make .iso file from ubuntu source I downloaded from kernel.ubuntu.com?

Tags: system-installation, iso, custom-distributions

from [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947833/where-to-get-ubuntu-linux-kernel-source-package), I learned that I can get the whole ubuntu 20.04 source by

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git
```

But I can't find information about how to make .iso file from the source.
What I want to do is to add some prints to the source code to debug ubuntu install failure to my qemu virtual machine, or better yet, to run the installation using debugger.

Comment: What you are cloning here is the kernel, you will probably also need the rootfs ... after that you'll need to build the kernel with whatever modification you made to it ... this will generate the initramfs or ( initial ram filesystem) this can be passed to qemu-system-{arch} using `-kernel` then you can download the rootfs archive  ( probably named rootfs.tar.gz) and convert it to an image file using a either `mkisofs` command or `dd` command and pass it to -hda

Comment: @SaleemKhair Sorry for the late response. yes, I thought I should use only the .iso file but  with a simple test could see that I can install ubuntu with the kernel image and initrd file from inside the iso file. Thanks!